# Format timestamp output using sed

Tags: linux, sed, timestamp

I'm new to Linux in general, I want to change the format of my log file using sed command:

Current format:

```
2016-09-27file.txt::2016-09-27 18:00:00
```

Expected format:

```
2016-09-27file.txt::2016/09/27-18:00:00
```

How should I write the sed command?

Thanks,
Z

Comment: That is a seriously messed up log file format with `:`s both separating fields and used within fields and with the date specified twice. Can you fix that at it's source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following shows how to do it on a single line:

`echo "2016-09-27file.txt::2016-09-27 18:00:00" |  sed  's/\([0-9]*\)-\([0-9]*\)-\([0-9]*\) /\1\/\2\/\3-/'`

The `regexp` part matches for the date part that you want to replace, which is also split-ed into sub-expression to make those part referable on replacement part.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i 's/-///g' "$filename"

sed -i 's/ /-/g' "$filename"
```

Try this.

Comment: need to use different delimiter like `s|-|/|g` or escape it like `s/-/\//g` .. good thinking for alternate solution, however, this will change the date at beginning to string as well which is not what OP requested...

Comment: Yes u are right, i forgot about the first date. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `perl` version

```
$ echo '2016-09-27file.txt::2016-09-27 18:00:00' | perl -pe 's#::\K(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) #$1/$2/$3-#'
2016-09-27file.txt::2016/09/27-18:00:00
```

- `::\K` positive lookbehind, check if `::` is present, won't get replaced
- `(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})` capture dates
- `$1/$2/$3-` reformatting, `$1` corresponds to capture group `(\d{4})` and so on for others
- `#` is delimiter used than usual `/` which makes unnecessary to escape the `/` in replacement string